Why are [tag:prg] and [tag:prng] distinct?
I'm not sure if there is a real difference between a Pseudo-Random-Generator (PRG) and a Pseudo-Random-Number-Generator (PRNG), whiches tag is synomized with random-number-generator.
I think we should make prg, csprng, pseudo-random-generator synonyms of the tag random-number-generator.
Theoretically I could do this, but I wanted to ask here, to make sure there wasn't a reason behind the different tags.

The list of randomness related tags is longer than that: [tag:random-number-generator] [tag:randomness] [tag:pseudo-random-generator] [tag:csprng]

@CodesInChaos, nice finding! I only found prg because it had a poor tag wiki entry, but it looks like I actually missed those. I proposed most of them for synonymization with rng (spelled out). However I think randomness has its applications for questions about the nature of randomness.

Related question (self deleted) Do the tags “random-number-generator” and “pseudo-random-generator” describe the same thing?

@CodesInChaos, well thank you for the related question, but unfortunaly I don't have the 2k rep yet to view such questions...

@SOJPM: There's not a lot there, basically it just links to this answer and asks whether there is a difference between the tags and, if so, what it is. No comments or answers.

There is a distinction between pseudorandom generators, as defined in theoretical computer science, and pseudorandom number generators in general.  Whether it's a useful distinction to make for tags on this site is a matter I will, at least for now, leave for others to argue.
(Unless somebody chimes in with "yes!", I'm somewhat inclined to assume "no" by default.  But I'm also perfectly fine with leaving them separate, if someone finds the separation useful.)
As for the other tags mentioned above, I do agree that prg should certainly be a synonym for pseudo-random-generator, just like rng and prng already are for random-number-generator.  I also agree that on this site csprng should be a synonym of random-number-generator; this is Crypto.SE, so any on-topic discussion of (pseudo)random number generators pretty much has to concern those that have, or are claimed to have, at least some level of cryptographic security.
(There might be an argument to be made for having a separate tag for "true" hardware RNGs, as opposed to PRNGs, but so far nobody seems to have created one.  I'd say wait and see; if there really is a need, someone will create it.)
I also agree that randomness should remain separate, since it's mainly being used for cryptographic schemes that consume random numbers instead of generating them.  Of course, there will naturally be some overlap in questions between this tag and random-number-generator, but that's perfectly fine and to be expected.

I see a seemingly random assortment of the mentioned tags being used by current and past questions. Shouldn't these all be normalized to [tag:random-number-generator]? Or were the mentioned synonyms never implemented?

@rmalayter: Looks like they weren't. I just went and added a suggested synonym from [tag:csprng] to [tag:random-number-generator], but it still takes four users (or, more likely, a single moderator) to approve it. I can't suggest a synonym from [tag:prg] to [tag:pseudo-random-generator], because there's apparently already a reverse synonym from [tag:pseudo-randomgenerator] (with a missing hyphen) to [tag:prg], and the system considers those too similar. (By default, non-existent tags that only differ from an existing one by a hyphen are autocorrected.) That probably needs a mod to sort it out.

@SEJPM & Ilmari: I’ve approved, swapped and merged things a bit. Simply ping me if I forgot something.
